# Некорректно определяется ширина документа в браузерах на сайте

Tags: битрикс, google-chrome, кроссбраузерность

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: есть сайт, работает на битрикс. В браузерах Chrome, Opera, Edge некорректно определяется ширина окна. В Firefox и Safari все норм. Отслеживаю поведение по `window.innerWidth`. Поведение такое:

- При реальной ширине 0-245px значение `window.innerWidth` в 4 раза больше
- При реальной ширине 246-980px значение `window.innerWidth` 980px (иногда 981px)
- При реальной ширине выше 980px `window.innerWidth` такое же

Следствие такого поведения -- неправильно отрабатывают `media` стили.

Пробовали отключать все стили/скрипты, результатов не дало. Сторонних модулей на сайте нет, только стандартные битриксовские. Проблема сохраняется в административной части сайта.

Может кто знает, с чем это может быть связано?

Если нужны дополнительные данные -- приложу

Пример, как это выглядит:

[image]

Comment: Это связано с тем, что у тебя какой-то элемент вылезает за экран. Но хром не хочет показывать полосы прокрутки, а просто начинает масштабировать страницу. Это глюк  движка. Вон тот блок с текстом наверху подозрительный.

Comment: @ВикторКарев, первое, что пришло в голову. Значит, что если снести всю разметку, то проблема исчезнет. Но при удалении всей разметки результат не меняется, devtools показывают все тот же размер 980px

Comment: Смотри на блок ```body``` и на блоки, вылезающие за него. Исправь разметку, при необходимости используя ```overflow-x: auto;```, добейся того, чтобы не было блоков, вылезающих из ```body```.

Comment: @ВикторКарев, добавил ответ

Comment: Подобный глюк в хроме иногда происходит и при указании meta viewport.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема оказалась смешной, забыли указать размер viewport'a. После добавления в `head` строчки `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` все заработало нормально.